# In Genesis 1:29 are there exceptions or limitations regarding "every herb bearing seed" that God gave man to eat?

Tags: genesis, authorial-intent, plants-and-animals

Genesis 1:29 says:

> And God said, Behold, **I have given you every** herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of **all the earth**, and **every** tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed; to you it shall be for [meat](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/402.htm).

Although this is spoken to Adam, in Genesis 9:3 God says to Noah:

> Every moving thing that liveth shall be meat for you; **even as the green herb** have I given you all things.

The word translated *meat* is [**לאכלה**](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/402.htm), and it seems to mean *consumption*, rather than just literal chewing and swallowing of food.

Does this mean *every single* plant, including poisonous, medicinal, and psychedelic herbs, belongs to mankind to consume however we wish? Or are there restrictions, either from the word **לאכלה** or in other parts of Scripture, as to how we may consume plants?

Comment: He also gave Eve to Adam, but not to do literally whatever he wants to or with her. Much less to eat her.

Comment: That’s kind of silly @SolaGratia. God never said Adam could eat Eve, but He explicitly says plants are to be “eaten” or “consumed”. For example, I can grow a tree, break off a branch, and kill somebody with it. However, God never authorized such a thing.

Comment: God gave us reason. It's not reasonable to eat poisonous animals or plants, is it.

Comment: Yes, God did give us reason. That’s why most humans don’t inject themselves with heroin, and why the newer generation is not smoking cigarettes. Telling people they have permission to eat nightshade is not going to increase the number of people who eat nightshade, because it’s clearly not a smart choice. My issue is with the people who get addicted to opiates that doctors prescribe, then move on to heroin because it’s cheaper and easier to obtain. If they could grow their own medicine that God gave us, it seems *reason*able people would choose a less dangerous route to ween themselves.

Comment: I don't know how your concern is relevant to exegesis..

Comment: Can you please clarify your question to make explicit your concern? Is it regarding property rights? Or poisonous or pleasurable plants? Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator I edited the question to clarify. Does that help?

Comment: Well, it would be helpful to be more specific. For example, "Does it mean that to drink Orange Tekoe tea, smoke Medi-Bud or strangle my neighbor with an Ivy are my inalienable rights?" I think that's off topic.

Comment: @Ruminator I’m really wondering if God ever revokes or places restrictions on this gift at any time. It seems we are even permitted to chemically modify plants to prepare new substances such as alcohol. Although there are many warnings against alcohol, it’s never actually prohibited. Also, there is nothing in the text that implies we can harm another person with plants- especially by using them to cause physical damage. God says they are to be לְאָכְלָֽה- which I understand to be a little bit different than “food”, as it seems to imply *any* form of “consumption”.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ruminator. Hopefully I’ll get some of those close votes removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right of use/access is implied in the right of ownership. If you own it you can use it. Access/use can also be granted explicitly without conferring ownership. An example might be allowing a guest to use your cottage for the weekend. I believe the latter is in view here.

God never confers his ownership on anyone else. He is the almighty.

The text does say "every green herb bearing seed". Like Mark 7:18-19 it seems to not be aware that some herbs bearing seed are toxic to humans:

https://www.thisoldhouse.com/ideas/12-deadliest-garden-plants

However I believe what that the best way to view these passages is in relation to religious cleaning rather than to safety. That is, God was saying that he would punish someone for hunting and killing animals but not for eating plants at that time:

> Gen 10:8  And Cush begat Nimrod: he began to be a mighty one in the
>   earth.  Gen 10:9  He was a mighty hunter [a predator] before the LORD:
>   wherefore it is said, Even as Nimrod the mighty hunter [predator]
>   before [defying] the LORD.

In fact, Torah doesn't seem to have the concept of clean/unclean plants at all. The marijuana and coca plants are just as ceremonially clean as are tomatoes and pumpkins. God made all the plants and all the plants are "very good". Some are not food.

To to get back to the question: God owns everything because he made it and he didn't sell anything:

> Psa 24:1  A Psalm of David. **The earth is the LORD'S, and the fulness
>   thereof**; the world, and they that dwell therein.  Psa 24:2  **For he
>   hath founded it** upon the seas, and established it upon the floods.

We know because of the kosher laws that God retained the right to dictate what people can and can't eat:

> Act 11:7  And I heard a voice saying unto me, Arise, Peter; slay and
>   eat.  Act 11:8  But I said, Not so, Lord: for nothing common or
>   unclean hath at any time entered into my mouth.  Act 11:9  But the
>   voice answered me again from heaven, What God hath cleansed, that call
>   not thou common.

### Medicine

But what about other kinds of consumption, such as curing diseases with herbal extracts and such? The passage in question does not seem to aspire to be the passage of scripture that lists poisonous plant. So it appears that if you want to eat Rhododendron, have at it. Someone asked, "Can I get to heaven if I eat pork?" To which the preacher replied, "Yep, you might even get there quicker!"

One passage we can look to for some more data is this:

> Psa 104:13  He watereth the hills from his chambers: the earth is
>   satisfied with the fruit of thy works.  Psa 104:14  He causeth the
>   grass to grow for the cattle, and herb for the service of man: that he
>   may bring forth food out of the earth;  Psa 104:15  And wine that
>   maketh glad the heart of man, and oil to make his face to shine, and
>   bread which strengtheneth man's heart.

It certainly appears that the Psalm sees the making of wine to be a God-given process. The alcohol in wine then does double duty as an antiseptic:

> 1Ti_5:23  Drink no longer water, but use a little wine for thy
>   stomach's sake and thine often infirmities.

The adding of wine for its alcohol to water is, I think, the kind of extract the question has in mind. So I'm going to say that this speaks to the point.

I notice it also says that the wine itself is intoxicating and that too is God's intention for the stuff.

Also I notice that the Psalmist definitely has a fondness for the drink he **seems** to also have a fondness for marijuana:

> Psa 104:14  **He causeth the grass to grow for the cattle, and herb
>   for the service of man: that he may bring forth food out of the
>   earth;  Psa 104:15  And wine that maketh glad the heart of man**, and
>   oil to make his face to shine, and bread which strengtheneth man's
>   heart.

To my mind that is celebrating the bounty of the land:

- plants for the cattle
- plants for man: food, wine AND olive oil to rub on his face to feel like a young man again
- plants to smoke?

If God gave man wine to bring a bit of pleasure, the abuse of which brings endless grief I find it unthinkable that he did not also give to man and for man's service, pleasure AND health the one plant that seemed to escape Eden. Perhaps it is the sweet, benign and pleasurable nature of marijuana that draws down so much hatred and persecution.

However, like today formulations for curing and such in the ANE were often the wares of charlatans and so the whole of medicine, I think, was largely considered as the realm of the world, not of the assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don’t mean it as though God has given up His ownership to us. I mean has God given each individual person *every single* plant on the earth- to grow and consume (לְאָכְלָֽה) as we please? Such as cannabis, poppy, peyote, coca, etc. I can’t even find any restrictions in the Law of Moses.

Comment: @anonymouswho Hmm, yeah, I don't see any particular reference to psychoactive plants in the Bible. I would probably extrapolate on judicious use based on what it has to say about alcohol (which is a lot, and not all striking the same note). Tip: Please put the thrust of your concern into your question, which you can do by editing it now. Note that the question as you just asked it might be more exegesis than hermeneutics (the answer might not rely on this one verse as a proof text), in which case you could ask it on Christianity and/or Judaism SE.

Comment: Don't forget nightshade and other deadly poisonous plants.  You need to exercise a certain amount of judgment.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone. I put “as we please” to indicate that it’s something we would actually want to do. I don’t think anyone *wants* to eat nightshade, just as I don’t *want* to process poppy to make and consume heroin.

Comment: @Keelan I edited the question to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Note even nightshade has its uses.  It is used in the drops that dilate your eyes.  It causes your eyes to dilate by paralyzing those muscles.  Of course if you eat it and it paralyzes your heart and breathing muscles, you die.

Comment: I've downvoted this. Showing your work is a requirement on this site. This answer is little more than a personal opinion.

Comment: I upvoted and I’m considering accepting the answer. I recognize that all plants are not good, and that’s why I’m asking if we have permission to consume plants however we want. As @PerryWebb says- even nightshade has medicinal value, and I assume we are allowed to extract those medicinal qualities and consume them into our bodies through our eyes. Is there anything restricting this type of usage?

Comment: I'll add my answer to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added a comment to Lucian’s answer with more details also.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean every single plant belongs to each individual person to grow and consume as we please ?

No. Because, through sin, death entered the world. Notice that the following verse reads :

> [Genesis 1:30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_1:30&version=KJV&interface=print) And to **every beast** of the earth, and to **every fowl** of the air, and to **every thing that creepeth** upon the earth, wherein there is life, I have given **every green herb** for meat: and it was so.

Obviously, we do not live in a paradisaical utopia anymore, wherein all animals are herbivores. Their once-benign nature became altered; and so did that of the plants, many of which are now harmful.

---

> [Genesis 9:2-3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_9:2-3&version=KJV&interface=print) And the fear of you and the dread of you shall be upon **every beast** of the earth, and upon **every fowl** of the air, upon **all that moveth** upon the earth, and upon **all the fishes** of the sea; into your hand are they delivered. **Every moving thing** that liveth shall be meat for you; even as **the green herb** have I given you **all things** [ mentioned above ].

**Hint :** Notice something missing from before the expression *the green herb* ?

---

> Does this mean every single plant, including poisonous, medicinal, and [psychedelic herbs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyAFnV90Wqc&t=40), belongs to each individual person to grow and consume as we please ?

Only to the extent to which they contain seeds (i.e., fruits and vegetables) :

> [Genesis 1:29](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_1:29&version=KJV&interface=print) And God said : *Behold, I have given you **every herb bearing seed**, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is **the fruit of a tree yielding seed**; to you it shall be for meat*.

Grass and leaves don't exactly contain seeds within themselves; indeed, the latter seem to have been given only to animals, since humans don't exactly walk on all fours, chewing greenery, as beasts usually do :

> [Genesis 1:30](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_1:30&version=KJV&interface=print) And to **every beast** of the earth, and to **every fowl** of the air, and to **every thing that creepeth** upon the earth, wherein there is life, I have given **every green herb** for meat: and it was so.

After [Noah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noah)'s [Flood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_flood_narrative), the list of [Genesis 1:29](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_1:29&version=KJV&interface=print) is extended to include all animals, and certain herbs :

> [Genesis 9:2-3](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_9:2-3&version=KJV&interface=print) And the fear of you and the dread of you shall be upon **every beast** of the earth, and upon **every fowl** of the air, upon **all that moveth** upon the earth, and upon **all the fishes** of the sea; into your hand are they delivered. **Every moving thing** that liveth shall be meat for you; even as **the green herb** have I given you **all things**.

Again, humans don't exactly eat grass, so, as I've already pointed out above, the absence of the words *all* and *every* before the phrase *the green herb* may not be completely coincidental.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this seems to ignore Genesis 9:3, in which God reinstates (after the so-called *fall of man*) that every green herb belongs to Noah- even though Genesis 1:29 wasn’t spoken to Noah.

Comment: @anonymouswho: Better now ?

Comment: I’m not sure. Do you mean the dietary laws are missing?

Comment: +1 For these interesting thoughts. Could it be that *none* of the plants were poisonous in the beginning, before the Fall of Man? That would perhaps explain why Genesis 1:30 says "every green herb" but Genesis 9:3 omits the word "every." It seems that St. Basil the Great (see paragraph 4 of http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/32015.htm), however, disagreed with this interpretation, but thought that God even created noxious plants on Day 3.

Comment: @anonymouswho: The words *all* and *every* are missing before the expression *green herbs* in Genesis 9:2-3, despite being present everywhere else, not just there, but in Genesis 1:29-30 as well.

Comment: @Lucian The text says *every* moving thing is food, and then God says *even as* or “**just like** when I gave you the green herb, I have given you **all**”. I do like your way of thinking though, and I wish more people would apply that thought process to the rest of Scripture, but it doesn’t seem to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Pascal'sWager. I enjoyed reading it. I agree with Basil when he says “There are even circumstances where poisons are useful to men; with mandrake doctors give us sleep; with opium they lull violent pain. Hemlock has ere now been used to appease the rage of unruly diseases; and many times hellebore has taken away long standing disease. These plants, then, instead of making you accuse the Creator, give you a new subject for gratitude.”

Comment: @anonymouswho: I have extended the answer to reflect the latest changes to the body of the question.

Comment: Interesting thoughts, though Basil does seem to disagree with this interpretation also. You’re answer satisfies my intention, because as far as I know, all of the psychedelic and medicinal herbs *do* contain seed; although the very illegal male cannabis plant *hemp* does not- but it’s really an industrial crop. However, I’m not so sure I’m convinced this is the correct answer. The Hebrew for *seed* is [זֶ֗רַע](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/2233.htm) and it means *descendants*. Is there a reason why זֶ֗רַע should only be restricted to “seed”?

Comment: Also, what’s up with the video you linked to *psychedelic herbs*? I didn’t understand a word of it, but it was very fun to watch lol.

Comment: @anonymouswho: (a). I'm not entirely sure what you find so suspicious or mystifying about a very plain and literal reading of the text. (b). The Bible has many verses. Just because a certain action does not infringe upon one of them does not imply that it does not infringe upon others (James 2:10). (c) Coffee certainly contains seeds. (d). All words have a basic meaning, from which all others are derived. Seed refers primarily to the actual, physical seed both plants and animals, including men. Metaphorically, it can sometimes also refer to descendants, but this meaning is secondary.

Comment: @Lucian I don’t find the text to be suspicious or mystifying. When I read the verses, they seem to clearly say that all plants have been given to us to consume however we desire- but for some reason you (and many other people) disagree with that. I’m not sure what James 2:10 has to do with plants. I think I need to ask a separate question about זֶ֗רַע

Comment: @anonymouswho: Bluntly speaking, there are no animals with poisonous flesh (that were known to the ancient Hebrews), but poisonous mushrooms (to give an everyday example) are well-known. So how can one in good conscience say that the same God who forbade murder only a few chapters earlier (Cain and Abel) now all of a sudden allows self-murder, by giving us all plants to consume however we desire ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80950/discussion-between-anonymouswho-and-lucian).

Comment: I’ve thought about this more and decided to upvote this answer also. I feel like only the last part is relevant though, because I don’t understand how “death entering the world” means people cannot grow and consume plants however they please. I understand some are harmful, and it would be wise to avoid them, but nothing about God’s curse on the ground implies that He revoked His gift. I agree with what you say about plants containing seeds, but I’m also wondering if there are any restrictions. For example, are humans permitted to pack herbs tightly together, burn them, and inhale the smoke?

Comment: The passages from Genesis are about sustenance, not leisurely activities. Also, it's not clear to me to what extent, if any, was smoking practiced in [the Middle East in the millennia before Christ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Near_East).

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean every single plant, including poisonous, medicinal, and psychedelic herbs, belongs to each individual person to grow and consume as we please?

No.

Why? Assume God gave every single plant without exception to man for food to consume as he pleases. Then he gave them the Tree of Knowledge for food to consume as he pleases. This is contradiction.

> (Genesis 2:17) But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, **thou shalt not eat of it**: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.
>
> (Genesis 3:3) **But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of paradise, God hath commanded us that we should not eat**; and that we we should not touch it, lest perhaps we die.
>
> (Genesis 3:11) And he said to him: And who hath told thee that thou wast naked, but that thou hast eaten of the the tree whereof **I commanded thee that thou shouldst not eat**?
>
> (Romans 5:14) But death reigned from Adam unto Moses, even over them also who have not **sinned** after the similitude of the **transgression of Adam**, who is a figure of him who was to come.

---

Similarly, although Genesis 9:3 says "Every moving thing that liveth shall be meat for you," it would be incorrect to interpret this hyperliterally as meaning every-moving-thing-that-liveth-without-exception-whatsover. Otherwise, God would be approving of cannibalism, and it would be OK to eat your neighbors.

---

The Hebrew word כל (*kal*) is translated into English as "every" or "all." It should be clear, however, that כל does not mean absoulutely-every-without-exception or absolutely-all-without-exception. Generally, it seems to carry a stronger meaning than the English word "many" but a weaker meaning than the ∀ (for all) symbol in mathematics. I could make analagous statements for the Greek word πας.

Here are some quick NT examples to illustrate my point. It shouldn't be hard to find OT examples as well.

a. "For **all** (παντες) have sinned, and come short of the glory of God" (Romans 3:23).
     Question: Did Jesus sin? Answer: No. Jesus is one "who did no sin, neither was guile found in his mouth." (1 Peter 2:22)

b. "And the same John had his raiment of camel’s hair, and a leathern girdle about his loins; and his meat was locusts and wild honey. Then went out to him Jerusalem, and **all** (πασα) Judaea, and **all** (πασα) the region round about Jordan, And were baptized of him in Jordan, confessing their sins" (Matthew 3:4-6).
     Question: Did every single person in Judaea go to John to Baptist and be baptized of him and confess their sins? Answer: Probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I disagree that God forbade the tree of knowledge, but we would have to chat about that. Suppose there are restrictions to how we may consume plants and which plants are permissible, because God only meant “almost all”. How are we to know what the restrictions are? In the Scriptures we have people extracting alcohol from plants, compressing plant matter and burning it in tents, extracting oils for various reasons from plants, etc. Yet we never have a single prohibition from any of it.

Comment: Also, I cannot find anything that forbades cannibalism in the Scriptures. It seems we are left to use our *reason* and personal responsibility on *many* different matters.

Comment: Exodus 20:13 seems to forbid unrestricted cannibalism.

Comment: I agree, as does Genesis 9:5-6. The fact is, some people do eat human flesh. Whether it’s “legal” to eat human flesh is irrelevant, because wouldn’t you agree that only someone who is suffering extreme starvation so that their brain is not working properly- or someone who’s brain just doesn’t work properly- would even consider such a thing?